# Is there a mechanism to automatically reorder code statements based on a variable?

Tags: c#

If you have a variable X and Y and you apply this code to them:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 0;
x++;
y = x;
out(y);
```

Then the order of the code is critical to the output.

**My question**: is there a keyword that has the computer run the code in a certain order, depending on a variable?

**selOrder** is a keyword that **I just made up** for the sake of this example. It gets a Boolean value and with it determines which line to execute first.

```
example:
{
      int x = 10;
      int y = 0;
      bool order = true;
      selOrder(order)
      {
          x++;
      }
      {
          y = x;
      }
      out(y);
}
```

out : 11

This example is quite ridiculous and it makes this question look pathetic, but I am completely serious, even though in this example this key word is useless. I have stumbled across many code scenarios where it could be quite nifty.

Comment: If you've seen examples where it *would* be useful, I suggest you post one of those instead...

Comment: I just want to know if there is a key word for it I don't see why a good example is needed

Comment: No, there is not a keyword for this.

Comment: if (val) something; something2; else something2; something;

Comment: @user2102280: As you wrote yourself: "this example is quite ridiculous and it makes this question look pathetic"

Answer (score 5):

There is no keyword for this in C#.  Here are some options:

```
if (order)
{
    x++;
    y = x;
}
else
{
    y = x;
    x++;
}
```

Or: (this lets you type each portion just once, but is more complicated to read and run)

```
Action firstAction = () => x++;
Action secondAction = () => y = x;
if (order)
{
    firstAction();
    secondAction();
}
else
{
    secondAction();
    firstAction();
}
```

Comment: You could also wrap the latter in a static method to allow reuse.